# how to compare data types in json

Tags: python

How to compare data types in JSON in Python.

For example:

```
{ "address" : "10.1.1.1", # string
  "read" : true, # boolean
  "date" : 123 # int
}
```

how to compare this JSON with another and match only data types , not the values?

another JSON could be:

```
{ "address" : "11.1.1.1", # string
  "read" : false, # boolean
  "date" : 321 # int
}
```

and i will detect changes only in data types.

Third JSON could be

```
{ "address" : "10.1.1.1", # string
  "read" : 123, # int
  "date" : true # boolean
}
```

and i want to get error , because "read" is now int type. not boolean.

I want to see something like an method in pact test "Like" matcher.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the expected result? "Comparing" is all fine and good, but what do you want to get out of it?

Comment: You can use ```type(variable)``` to get the type of that variable. With that tip should be able to compare types of values ^^

Comment: I think you can use https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. You can define schema and use it any time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first say that you'll convert your JSON to Python dicts:

```
d1 = json.loads(json1)
```

From here, to simply raise any sort of error if any two keys don't have values of the same type, do something along these lines:

```
for k, v in d1.items():
    if not issubclass(type(v), type(d2[k])):
        raise TypeError('{} does not match: {} vs. {}'.format(k, type(v), type(d2[k])))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if i have in JSON `true` i get an error "true is not defined".

Comment: Does that mean you copy and pasted your JSON into Python source code, like `d1 = {"read": true}`? Yeah, that won't work. You need to read the JSON *as string* from somewhere, like a file, and `json.load` it.